# 2D input for partial derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, input

If I input

```
D[f[x,y],x]
```

the output is $f^{(1,0)}[x,y]$. If I copy and paste this output then it works as an input as expected.

However, if I manually type the 2D input $f^{(1,0)}[x,y]$ using the key sequence

```
[f], [^], [(], [1], [,], [0], [)], [right arrow], [[], [x], [,], [y], []]
```

I get an error

```
Syntax::sntxf: "(" cannot be followed by "1,0)".
```

So my question is, how do I input the partial derivative in the concise form $f^{(1,0)}[x,y]$, rather than having to type `D[f[x,y],x]`?

Comment: You can enter it as `D[f[x, y], x]`, highlight the code, then `Evaluate in Place` to change its appearance to what you desire.

Comment: Bob Hanlon's comment is the closest to my actual intention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Why doe you call the former more "concise"?
2. If you look at `FullForm@D[f[x, y], x]` you will find it is
   `Derivative[1,0][f][x,y]`, which you can enter directly. I suspect you will call this "less concise".
3. You can enter `Grad` symbolically, which gets close to what you want (but as a list).
4. You can enter `D` symbolically, which is very concise and as close as possible to what you want, I think: "By using the character ∂, entered as `[esc]pd[esc]` or `\[PartialD]`, with subscripts".

Comment: I say more concise because it occupies less screen space. But my main interest in the 2D input form is not its conciseness, but rather the fact that it looks much closer to how I would usually typeset the derivative ($f_1(x,y)$) and, in my opinion, makes the notebook more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You could type in the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm), and then use the menu item `Cell | Convert To | StandardForm` (the OSX keyboard short cut is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) to convert it to the form you want. Here is an animation:

[image]